# Would it be possible to shoot lightning at someone?

Tags: weapons, electricity

Assuming that you could generate an electrical charge between your hands, and that you're actually insulated to prevent a backfiring effect: Would it be possible to guide the electrical charge between your hands to hit a specified target (say another human being, 5-20 meters away) as either an ongoing current (think *Star Wars*) or a thunderbolt (like a lightning strike, but between you and the target)?

Comment: finished reading the post and the linked wiki page about Electrolasers. The latter seems like a potential candidate for an answer, can't say for sure yet

Comment: JBH's link + this one: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22347/lightning-rifle?rq=1 do kinda make up for the (well, more than yes/no) answer I was looking for